# Trying to get property 'departamento' of non-object

Tags: laravel, get

Estoy tratando de visualizar el listado de los registros guardados en un crud, estoy recibiendo el siguiente error: **rying to get property 'departamento' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hoysi\resources\views\entregas\listado-entregas.blade.php)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

anteriormente e agregado la ruta del app, departamento y municipio

```php
use App\Departamento;
use App\Municipio;
```

**codigo del controlador**

la función ShowEntregas

anteriormente e usado el código para listar los registros de otros registros

```php
public function showEntregas(Request $request)
{
    $count               = Entrega::count();
    $departamentos_lista = Departamento::all();
    if ($request->cmbDepartamento) {
        $departamento = Departamento::find($request->cmbDepartamento);
        $geocodigoDepartamento = $departamento->geocodigo;
        $municipios_lista = DB::select('CALL SP_Fill_Municipios(?)', array($geocodigoDepartamento));
    } else {
        $municipios_lista = Municipio::all();
    }
    $filtro = "1";
    if ($request->cmbDepartamento) {
        $filtro .= " AND iddepartamento = '".$request->cmbDepartamento."'";
    }
    if ($request->cmbMunicipio) {
        $filtro .= " AND idmunicipio = '".$request->cmbMunicipio."'";
    }
    if ($request->txtBusqueda) {
        $filtro .= " AND nombre LIKE '%".$request->txtBusqueda."%'";
    }
    
    $entregas = Entrega::whereRaw($filtro)->paginate(15);

    return view('entregas.listado-entregas', [
        'count'               => $count,
        'entregas'            => $entregas,
        'departamentos_lista' => $departamentos_lista,
        'municipios_lista'    => $municipios_lista,
    ]);
}
```

**vista**

aquí esta el código del archivo lista de entregas

```xml
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead style="background: #84BE38; color: white;">
        <tr>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">NOMBRE DEL BENEFICIARIO</th>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">TIPO DE AYUDA</th>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">MIEMBROS</th>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">DEPARTAMENTO</th>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">MUNICIPIO</th>
            <th style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" nowrap>ACCIONES <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($entregas as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $item->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ config('const.entrega1')[$item->tipo_entrega] }}</td>
                <td align="center">{{ $item->num_miembros }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->departamento->departamento}}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->municipio->nombre }}</td>
                <td class="text-center d-flex">
                    <a href="{{ route('entregas.show', $item->identrega) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mx-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{ route('entregas.edit', $item->identrega) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs mx-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <form action="{{ route('entregas.destroy', $item->identrega)}}" method="post">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs mx-1" type="submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash btn-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Rutas**

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'],'/lista-entregas','EntregasController@showEntregas')->name('entregas.index');
```

[image: tabla entregas]

```php
class Departamento extends Model
{
    protected $table      = "departamento";
    protected $primaryKey = 'iddepartamento';
    public    $timestamps = false;
}
```

```php
class Municipio extends Model
{
    protected $table      = "municipio";
    protected $primaryKey = 'idmunicipio';
    public    $timestamps = false;
}
```

modelo

```
/**
 * Relacion departamento
 */
public function departamento()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Departamento', 'iddepartamento', 'iddepartamento');
}
```

```php
/**
 * Relacion municipio
 */
public function municipio()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Municipio', 'idmunicipio', 'idmunicipio');
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de ante mano muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Si quieres acceder a campos relacionados, debes utilizar `Entrega::with('departamento')`

Comment: @BetaM e agregado los modelos,

Comment: @BetaM 1 municipio pertenece a 1 departamento

Comment: @BetaM y 1 departamento puede pertenecer a varios municipios

Comment: proba esto <td>{{ $item->departamento->departamento ?? '-'}}</td>
el error dice que departamento no existe. la pregunta es cual de las dos. (eso es lo malo de repetir nombres por lo que no es una buena practica)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo usaría condicionales para ver lo del filtro y cargar las relaciones apropiadas con los método `->when()` y `->whereHas()`

```php
# Cargar relaciones 'departamento' y 'municipio' de Entrega 
$entregas = Entrega::with(['departamento', 'municipio'])
# Filtrar solo las entregas que estén asociadas a un departamento.
->whereHas('departamento', function ($departamento) use ($request) {
    # Cuando esté presente '$request->cmbDepartamento',
    # filtrar las entregas que tengan relación con ese departamento
    $departamento->when($request->cmbDepartamento, function ($entrega) use ($request) {
        $departamento->where('iddepartamento', $request->cmbDepartamento);
    });
})
# Filtrar solo las entregas que estén asociadas a un municipio.
->whereHas('municipio', function ($municipio) use ($request) {
    # Cuando esté presente '$request->cmbMunicipio',
    # filtrar las entregas que tengan relación con ese municipio
    $municipio->when($request->cmbMunicipio, function ($entrega) use ($request) {
        $municipio->where('idmunicipio', $request->cmbMunicipio)
    });
})
# Cuando esté presente '$request->txtBusqueda',
# filtrar las entregas por nombre
->when($request->txtBusqueda, function ($entrega) use ($request) {
    $entrega->where('nombre', $request->txtBusqueda);
})
->paginate(15);
```